# Pulling the HTML from a DNN site I created

Tags: visual-studio, dotnetnuke

Is there a way to see the HTML for each page of a DNN site I created? I need to insert this code into a project within Visual Studio 2017. Is there a good approach for this?

Comment: Right click the mouse and select "View source" (description can vary per browser).

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it out.